# Discord.py emoji maps to undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that makes the bot react to every message sent in a channel with an emoji, that is customizable. Right now, it gets the emoji from the message fine, but once it tries to use it in anything (writing to a file, in my case) It gives

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f914' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

It only does this with discord emojis, with any custom emojis, it works fine. All I need is the emoji as a string, or even an ID.

Comment: Could you show the how you're writing to the file?  You could specify the encoding when you open the file `open(filename, 'w+', encoding="UTF-8")`.  How are you running your bot?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I write to the file with ```with open(("path/%s-channelreactions.txt" % message.server.name), "a+") as reactfile:
reactfile.write("%s, %s\n" % (channel, reaction))```

Comment: Could you share the full error, which will include the line(s) of code that caused the error?  If it's the write, then adding `encoding="UTF-8"` to your `open` should fix it.  If it's on a `print`, then it's likely a limitation of the shell you're running the bot in.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I tried replacing the encoding like you said, (The error was pointing to the write) and it DOES write the correct character to the file (the emoji) but when it tries to react with it, it just doesnt react. When I try to list it into discord, it outputs "ðŸ¤”"...

Comment: Did you change the encoding when you read from the file too?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, I did.